# get routing information from several files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a *huge* number of routes, and I'd like to add in orders of magnitude more.  Is there any way to add a 'require' statement at the top of the routes file, and have some other file(s) house the additional routes?  I don't want the routes.rb file to be a mile long.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can take DHHs approach to this:

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper
  def draw(routes_name)
    instance_eval(File.read(Rails.root.join("config/routes/#{routes_name}.rb")))
  end
end

BCX::Application.routes.draw do
  draw :api
  draw :account
  draw :session
  draw :people_and_groups
  draw :projects
  draw :calendars
  draw :legacy_slugs
  draw :ensembles_and_buckets
  draw :globals
  draw :monitoring
  draw :mail_attachments
  draw :message_preview
  draw :misc

  root to: 'projects#index'
end
```

Comment: DHH = David Heinemeier Hansson = Creator of rails:)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
 add in config/application.rb:

```
config.paths["config/routes"] << Rails.root.join('config/routes/you_route_file.rb')
```